# Why i can`t throw Exception(checked) in a method that is invoked in a try catch statement?

Tags: java, exception

```
 public class simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print("hello ");
            throwit();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            System.out.print("caught ");
        }
    }

    public static void throwit(){  // line number 11
        throw new Exception();  // line number 12
    }
   }
```

why does it give me a compile error in line number 12.
If i use throws Exception for line number 11 then it work fine.
If i throw subclass of Exception(in line number 12) then it work properly... why so?...

I want to know actually what happen in back side(how does compiler shows error for this)?

Comment: If throwit throws a checked exception, it needs to declare that, regardless of what code calls throwit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a method there which is throwing a checked exception, but its method signature doesn't specify that it is able to do that. All checked exceptions have to be declared in the method signature, and explicitly handled by try/catch blocks or by rethrowing; that's what the definition of a checked exception is. :)

This line:

```
public static void throwit()
```

should be

```
public static void throwit() throws Exception
```

Comment: We should also note that it is almost certainly a BAD idea to throw `Exception` and declare a method as throwing `Exception`.  It makes it very difficult for the caller to do anything meaningful ... apart from log the Exception and bail out.  You should always throw  / declare more specific exceptions so that the caller can discriminate the expected ones from the unexpected ones.

Comment: Exactly... If i throw specific exception(For example "NullPointerException") then compiler won`t give error at all("throws Exception" is not needed for method signature also). This code just under stand the concept behind exception  handling only... Why i cant throw the Exception?...I want to know how compiler works here?..

Comment: If you throw an `unchecked` exception, the compiler doesn't give an error because its unchecked.  All sub-classes of RuntimeException and Error are unchecked the rest are checked.

Comment: @Guru That is the fundamental difference between a checked and an unchecked exception. Checked exceptions must be declared and handled. Uncheck exceptions can be thrown without a declaration or explicit handling. To test this, change "Exception" to "RuntimeException" throughout your code and you will find it compiles (with or without the try block). However, unchecked exceptions don't force users of your code to check for exceptions, so they should only be used for extreme cases, like unrecoverable errors, or exceptions which can't be catered for sensibly (eg, NullPointerExceptions)